# Problems with regex in Imask react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to implement a mask for input, for this I use the IMask library for react, you can throw your mask there, but this library counts its own regular expressions for each mask, and as a result it checks the entire line
here is the regex I wrote: `(^[IVXLCDM]{1,4}$)(^[A-Z]{2}$)\b(^[\d]{6}$)`, in general it works, but only when the entire line is written, and not each individual block, a separate group is written for the block, how can you also check the final line with such a mask?

```
mask: 'WW-TT-RR',
                    overwrite: 'shift',
                    definitions: {},
                    blocks: {
                        RR: {
                            mask: /(\d{6})/,
                        },
                        WW: {
                            mask: /([IVXLCDM]{1,4})/,
                        },
                        TT: {
                            mask: /([А-Я]{2})/,
                        },
                    },
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be with the way you are structuring your mask and blocks. As per the iMask library, the mask structure should follow a regular expression pattern where each character in the mask represents a block.

In your case, you have 'WW-TT-RR' as your mask. Each 'W', 'T', and 'R' represent blocks of your mask. Your `definitions` and `blocks` object should follow the mask structure and define each character (W, T, R) as a block.

Here is how you should implement it:

```js
mask: 'WW-TT-RR',
overwrite: true,
definitions: {
    'W': {
        mask: /[IVXLCDM]/,
    },
    'T': {
        mask: /[A-Z]/,
    },
    'R': {
        mask: /\d/,
    },
},
blocks: {
    'WW': {
        mask: 'WW',
        maxLength: 4,
    },
    'TT': {
        mask: 'TT',
        maxLength: 2,
    },
    'RR': {
        mask: 'RRRRRR',
    },
}
```

In this configuration:

- The 'W', 'T', 'R' in `definitions` define the mask for each character in your 'WW-TT-RR' mask.
- The 'WW', 'TT', 'RR' in `blocks` define the lengths of each block.
- `maxLength` is used to restrict the length of each block.
- The `overwrite` option is set to true to allow replacement of characters when typing at the middle or start of the input.

This way, the input will be validated block by block as you type. The whole line won't be required to pass the validation.
------------------------ update -----------------
try to follow this example

```
import React from 'react';
import IMask from 'imask';

const maskOptions = {
    mask: '{WW}-{TT}-{RR}',
    blocks: {
        WW: {
            mask: new IMask.MaskedPattern.Definition({
                validate: (char, pos, flags) => {
                    return /[IVXLCDM]/.test(char);
                },
                maxLength: 4,
            }),
        },
        TT: {
            mask: new IMask.MaskedPattern.Definition({
                validate: (char, pos, flags) => {
                    return /[A-Z]/.test(char);
                },
                maxLength: 2,
            }),
        },
        RR: {
            mask: new IMask.MaskedPattern.Definition({
                validate: (char, pos, flags) => {
                    return /\d/.test(char);
                },
                maxLength: 6,
            }),
        },
    },
};

export const MyInputComponent = () => {
    let inputRef = null;

    React.useEffect(() => {
        const mask = IMask(inputRef, maskOptions);
        return () => mask.destroy();
    }, [inputRef]);

    return <input ref={ref => inputRef = ref} />;
};
```

Comment: I did as you wrote, and nothing works, the characters WW-TT-RRRRRR just appear in the field and no characters are entered at all

Comment: and  TS say: "TS2322: Type '{ mask: RegExp; }' is not assignable to type 'PatternDefinition'.   Type '{ mask: RegExp; }' is not assignable to type 'string'."

Comment: check out I added an example try it

Comment: Thank you, but I also implemented it in my own way by the current moment)) Thank you for your help, I'm sure your option will come in handy, since functions are used there)